# RadMessageBox layout disturbed on Windows 7 Zoom

Tags: winforms, layout, telerik, controls, messagebox

I am using Telerik Controls Q12013 and it is working fine in default (100%) OS zoom but I am facing Layout problem `RadMessageBox` with 125% OS zoom in Windows 7.

Desktop [Right click] > Personalization > Display > 125% Zoom.

I am facing problem while using Theme "`VisualStudio2012Light`", "`TelerikMetro`", and "`TelerikMetroBlue`" but its working fine in default `Office2007` theme. I have attached some images for your better understanding.

[image: <code>RadMessageBox</code> is not displaying correctly]

[image: Windows 7 125% zoom]

[Edited]
after setting minimum width of MessageBox instance It looks like.
[image]
Problem is still same. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the message box minimum size prior showing it:

```
   RadMessageBox.Instance.MinimumSize = new Size(300, 200);
   RadMessageBox.Show("test");
```

If interested in more information you can read here: [WinForms Scaling at Large DPI Settings–Is It Even Possible?](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-)